# inserting 4 different files into 1 SQL table row in php

Tags: php, sql, parsing, insert

As the title says, i want to parse 4 different files and insert them into 1 sql row. I have parsed the files so i have the information, however its not inserting into my table.
This is the code I have. I eliminated the actual sql names and values to save time. My two main questions are 1) is this the right way to do this and 2) is there a better way.

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("reserve1", "root", "","server_31");
$dir = "/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Reserve1";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

        foreach(glob("*.json") as $filename) {
            $data = file_get_contents($filename);
            $array = json_decode($data, true);
            foreach($array[0]as $row) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO servers_updated (---)  
                        VALUES ('---)";
                $connect->query($sql);
            }


            foreach(glob("*_processor.json") as $filename) {
                $data = file_get_contents($filename);
                $info = json_decode($data, true);
                foreach($info[1] as $row) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO servers_updated 
                            (--- ) VALUES (---)";
                    $connect->query($sql);
            }

            foreach(glob("*_drives.json") as $filename) {
                $data = file_get_contents($filename);
                $info = json_decode($data, true);
                foreach($info[1] as $row) {
                    $sql=" INSERT INTO servers_updated (---) VALUES (---)";
                    $connect->query($sql);
                }

                foreach(glob("*_memory.json") as $filename) {
                    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
                    $stuff = json_decode($data, true);
                    foreach($stuff[1] as $row) { 
                        $sql =" INSERT INTO servers_updated  
                                (--- ) VALUES (----)";
                        $connect->query($sql);
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it me or it lacks one `}`?

Comment: It might, it would be from copying and pasting but you were right i was missing 1 at the end and added it.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I will take a read, thanks!